# dealing with "missing" times when setting data to xts

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like the following;

```
                Dates    Open   Close
1000  06/06/2019 0:05 244.599 244.524
1001  06/06/2019 0:04 244.592 244.599
1002  06/06/2019 0:03 244.564 244.592
1003  06/06/2019 0:02 244.809 244.564
1004  06/06/2019 0:01 244.849 244.809
1005       06/06/2019 245.080 244.849
1006 05/06/2019 23:59 245.092 245.080
1007 05/06/2019 23:58 245.253 245.092
1008 05/06/2019 23:57 244.858 245.253
1009 05/06/2019 23:56 244.643 244.863
1010 05/06/2019 23:55 244.720 244.643
```

Where row `1005` doesn't have a time stamp. I try to set my dates to `POSIXlt` format.

```
data$Dates <- gsub("/", "-", data$Dates)
data$Dates <- as.POSIXlt(strptime(data$Dates, format="%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M"))
```

Now my data looks like:

```
                   Dates    Open   Close
1000 2019-06-06 00:05:00 244.599 244.524
1001 2019-06-06 00:04:00 244.592 244.599
1002 2019-06-06 00:03:00 244.564 244.592
1003 2019-06-06 00:02:00 244.809 244.564
1004 2019-06-06 00:01:00 244.849 244.809
1005                <NA> 245.080 244.849
1006 2019-06-05 23:59:00 245.092 245.080
1007 2019-06-05 23:58:00 245.253 245.092
1008 2019-06-05 23:57:00 244.858 245.253
1009 2019-06-05 23:56:00 244.643 244.863
1010 2019-06-05 23:55:00 244.720 244.643
```

I am just wondering if there is a way around converting the times with no Hour or Minute data. It only occurs on the hour `0:00`

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(Dates = c("06/06/2019 0:05", "06/06/2019 0:04", 
"06/06/2019 0:03", "06/06/2019 0:02", "06/06/2019 0:01", "06/06/2019", 
"05/06/2019 23:59", "05/06/2019 23:58", "05/06/2019 23:57", "05/06/2019 23:56", 
"05/06/2019 23:55"), Open = c(244.599, 244.592, 244.564, 244.809, 
244.849, 245.08, 245.092, 245.253, 244.858, 244.643, 244.72), 
    Close = c(244.524, 244.599, 244.592, 244.564, 244.809, 244.849, 
    245.08, 245.092, 245.253, 244.863, 244.643)), row.names = 1000:1010, class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:

I just thought perhaps I should first split the column into two (one for dates and another for times) fill in the blank cells in the second column with `0:00` and paste back together.

Answer (score 2):

`parse_date_time` in the lubridate package will successively check alternative formats until it succeeds if you give it a vector of formats.  The separators and percent signs can be omitted from the format strings.

```
library(lubridate)

parse_date_time(data$Dates, c("dmYHM", "dmY"), tz = "")
```

giving:

```
 [1] "2019-06-06 00:05:00 EDT" "2019-06-06 00:04:00 EDT"
 [3] "2019-06-06 00:03:00 EDT" "2019-06-06 00:02:00 EDT"
 [5] "2019-06-06 00:01:00 EDT" "2019-06-06 00:00:00 EDT"
 [7] "2019-06-05 23:59:00 EDT" "2019-06-05 23:58:00 EDT"
 [9] "2019-06-05 23:57:00 EDT" "2019-06-05 23:56:00 EDT"
[11] "2019-06-05 23:55:00 EDT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, one possibility could be:

```
data %>%
 mutate(Dates = ifelse(nchar(Dates) == 10, paste(Dates, "0:00", sep = " "), Dates),
        Dates = as.POSIXct(Dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))

                 Dates    Open   Close
1  2019-06-06 00:05:00 244.599 244.524
2  2019-06-06 00:04:00 244.592 244.599
3  2019-06-06 00:03:00 244.564 244.592
4  2019-06-06 00:02:00 244.809 244.564
5  2019-06-06 00:01:00 244.849 244.809
6  2019-06-06 00:00:00 245.080 244.849
7  2019-06-05 23:59:00 245.092 245.080
8  2019-06-05 23:58:00 245.253 245.092
9  2019-06-05 23:57:00 244.858 245.253
10 2019-06-05 23:56:00 244.643 244.863
11 2019-06-05 23:55:00 244.720 244.643
```

Here, for rows containing just the 10 characters, it combines the date with `0:00`.

The same with `base R`:

```
data$Dates <- ifelse(nchar(data$Dates) == 10, paste(data$Dates, "0:00", sep = " "), data$Dates)
as.POSIXct(data$Dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: This works great! There is now no missing values in the data, so the problem was with just the `0:00` hours.